# Liferay Project Build Success but Project Not Created

Tags: eclipse, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am trying to create a new theme plugin project in Eclipse using Liferay IDE but getting an error saying Project cannot be created Check Eclipse log.

Eclipse logs says this

```
    !SESSION 2015-05-11 12:36:37.793 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-11 12:38:55.389
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-11 12:38:55.390
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Pawan'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.apache.ivyde.eclipse 1 0 2015-05-11 12:40:03.667
!MESSAGE starting IvyDE plugin

!ENTRY org.apache.ivyde.eclipse 1 0 2015-05-11 12:40:03.680
!MESSAGE IvyDE plugin started

!ENTRY com.liferay.ide.project.core 4 0 2015-05-11 14:30:49.541
!MESSAGE Error creating Liferay plugin project.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431334488475' does not exist
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.doCreateNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:182)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.NewLiferayProjectProvider.createNewProject(NewLiferayProjectProvider.java:45)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.execute(NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.java:109)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOp$Impl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard.performFinish(SapphireWizard.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard$3.run(SapphireWizard.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431334488475' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1298)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1191)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1160)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.doCreateNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:176)
    ... 6 more
!SUBENTRY 1 com.liferay.ide.project.core 4 0 2015-05-11 14:30:49.542
!MESSAGE Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431334488475' does not exist
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431334488475' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1298)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1191)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1160)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.doCreateNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:176)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.NewLiferayProjectProvider.createNewProject(NewLiferayProjectProvider.java:45)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.execute(NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.java:109)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOp$Impl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard.performFinish(SapphireWizard.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard$3.run(SapphireWizard.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)

!ENTRY com.liferay.ide.project.core 4 0 2015-05-11 14:45:13.804
!MESSAGE Error creating Liferay plugin project.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431335706606' does not exist
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.doCreateNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:182)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.NewLiferayProjectProvider.createNewProject(NewLiferayProjectProvider.java:45)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.execute(NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.java:109)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOp$Impl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard.performFinish(SapphireWizard.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard$3.run(SapphireWizard.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431335706606' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1298)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1191)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1160)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.doCreateNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:176)
    ... 6 more
!SUBENTRY 1 com.liferay.ide.project.core 4 0 2015-05-11 14:45:13.804
!MESSAGE Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431335706606' does not exist
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'D:\Liferay_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431335706606' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1298)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1191)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1160)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.doCreateNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:176)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.NewLiferayProjectProvider.createNewProject(NewLiferayProjectProvider.java:45)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.execute(NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.java:109)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOp$Impl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard.performFinish(SapphireWizard.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard$3.run(SapphireWizard.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Please assist. I am new to liferay.

**Liferay Version**: Liferay Portal Tomcat 6.2 CE GA4
**SDK Version**: liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga4

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on the forum, this indeed is a **bug**.

> This is a known issue with GA4 and IDE. The project 
>   is created on-disk, it's just not able to be imported successfully -
>   so you can manually File->Import->Liferay->Liferay Projects from
>   Plugins SDK and import the project by choosing your SDK and it should
>   show you the project.

[Source] (https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/52972178 "Liferay Forum")

Cheers,
Pawan